# How to store environment settings in a Windows Phone application

Tags: windows-phone-8, configuration

I'm trying to find the best solution in Windows Phone development for configuring environment-specific information.

These may include for example URLs that are different for development, test and production.
They also should be configurable for each developer, alowing them to run the code with his or her own environment setup.

Another example would be the Live SDK ClientID. I'm currently playing around with this SDK, but obviously you don't want to check in your key on GitHub. So hard coding it like every example does is not an option :)

As far as I can see, there is no notion of App.config and appSettings with Windows Phone, and all search results point me to use LocalStorage, which is NOT what I'm after.

Anyone have some experience to this? It must be a standard need for large enterprise applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your settings in IsolatedStorage by IsolatedStorageSettings class.

This may help you :) 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769510(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769510%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714090(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714090%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I'm looking for. These are not user settings and to add defaults to the IsolatedStorage you still need to hard-code them first, what I don't want to do.